# How to get the first element result in Php using foreach?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, iteration

I tried to have this multi-dimensional array on Quotes>Sections>Departments
I have a problem with getting the first iteration of the foreach-ed

```
$Department->getActuals();

$actuals = array();

foreach($quotes as $quoteID => $Quotes) {
                $invoiceTotal = $Quotes->getInvoicedValue();
                if($invoiceTotal['Total'] > 0) {
                    $labourCost = 0;
                    $actualHours = 0;
                    $sections = $Quotes->getSections();
                    foreach ($sections as $Sections) {
                        $departments = $Sections->getDepartments();
                        foreach($departments as $Department) {
                            $actuals = $Department->getActuals(null, null, false);
                            Console::Log('actuals', $actuals);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Console::Log('actuals', $actuals);

How to get the first element result in Php using foreach?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @gview Sorry for the late reply. 

I can't get the first iteration of foreached $Department.

$actual variable when consoled gives multiple results.

`code`  Console::Log('actuals', $actuals); `code`


`code` $actuals = $Department->getActuals(null, null, false); `code`
Thanks  in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Is $actuals an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $actuals is an array, you can access the first element via array notation.  Arrays in php are 0 based.

```
Console::Log('actuals', $actuals[0]);
```

Based on your statement that $actuals is an array with a number of associative keys within, you can get a human readable form using print_r, and passing the true parameter to return the output rather than printing it.

```
Console::Log('actuals', print_r($actuals, true));
```

Comment: My apology for super late reply. This problem was year ago, and I think was resolved. Thanks gview for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution was answered by gview

```
Console::Log('actuals', $actuals[0]);
```